# Running Apache Tomcat 6 on 64 bit Windows 7 Prof

Tags: java, apache, tomcat6

I have an old web application which was built using jsp and Microsoft Access as backend and is successfully running on Apache Tomcat version 4 hosted by Win XP 32 bit system.

I have got an assignment to port this web application to a Windows 7 Professional 64 bit system which is already in private network whose IP ranges from 192.9.21.01 to 192.9.21.36, subnet mask is 255.255.0.0. As target system (IP is 192.9.21.16) is installed with Microsoft Office 32 bit, I decided to go for 32 bit Tomcat and Java.

Then  I installed JRE 6 update 45 and Apache Tomcat 6.0.43 as a service successfully. At this point, the default home page 192.9.21.16:8080 works fine from browser of local system. But it is not available from any other system in the same network.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that your machines firewall is blocking access to port 8080. Try either create an exception in the Windows 7 machines firewall, or disable it completely.